# Rickshaw: Graph max y-axis is cutoff

Tags: javascript, rickshaw

I'm trying to use Rickshaw to display data in our JS app, but the y-axis is sometimes cutoff:

[image: Cuttoff Y]

I have tried several variants of "display:visible", but nothing seems to work. Do you know how to fix this? (i.e. show the full "$100")?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add padding to the `Rickshaw.Graph` object itself when creating/instantiating it:

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
  element: document.getElementById("chart"),
  renderer: 'line',
  stroke: true,
  series: seriesVar,
  padding: {top: 0.02, left: 0.02, right: 0.02, bottom: 0.02}
} );
```

See [Rickshaw homepage](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw#padding) for padding explanation.

Comment: This also solves the problem of highest and lowest data points appearing to get cut off at the top and bottom of the graph. Thanks!